# arraylist empty after being populated inside Volley onResponse callback method

Tags: android, arraylist

i am facing a very weird issue..i populate an arraylist with String values in onResponse method of Volley library...logging the values of arraylist inside onResponse is showing that arraylist is not empty...but when i do the same before the arraylist is reuturned from the method is empty...

```
private ArrayList<String> getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner() {

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayFirmNamesRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_FIRMNAMES,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject firmObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String firmName = firmObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_FIRM_NAME);
                                firmNamesArrayList.add(firmName);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d(debugTag, "return inside onResponse" + firmNamesArrayList);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(debugTag, "response error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        Log.d(debugTag, "return before adding Request" + firmNamesArrayList);
        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayFirmNamesRequest, AppConfig.TAG_FIRMNAMES_REQUEST);

        return firmNamesArrayList;
    }
```

can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: The reason is that the onResonse is a callback method, meaning it will be called back later, potentially on another thread. The jsonArrayFirmNamesRequest will not block meaning that the original thread wii continue and so it will be empty. Also it won't be called untl the request queue processes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to lordoku and after searching a bit..i found out a solution..what i did to solve the issue was to create a callback interface and execute the callback method getFirmNamesOnSuccess() of the interface when the onResponse has been finished...

interface FirmNamesRequestCallback

```
private interface FirmNamesRequestCallback{
    void getFirmNamesOnSuccess(JSONArray firmName);
}
```

inside getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner(final FirmNamesRequestCallback firmNamesRequestCallback) which is being called with the interface as parameter 
and specifically inside onResponse the callback method of the interface is executed

```
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    firmNamesRequestCallback.getFirmNamesOnSuccess(response);
                }
```

getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner is called with a new object of the interface and inside the implementation of the callback method which is executed only after onResponse is finished i populate the arrayadapter...

```
 getFirmNamesToPopulateSpinner(new FirmNamesRequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void getFirmNamesOnSuccess(JSONArray firmName) {
                    //do some stuff here the JSONArray response
                }
            });
```