# Android Volley after adding items to arraylist still empty after adding

Tags: android, multithreading, android-volley

I am using volley in my android app and i add Torrent objects to the Arraylist and it fills the list but after the program exits this method getAllDetails() the arraylist is empty..could someone please explain what is really going on???

```
private void getAllDetails() {
    String URL = MOVIE_DETAILS_URL + movie.getId() + CAST_URL;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject dataObject = response.getJSONObject(Keys.DATA);
                JSONObject movieObject = dataObject.getJSONObject(Keys.MOVIE);
                JSONArray torrentsArray = movieObject.getJSONArray(Keys.TORRENTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < torrentsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject torrentObject = torrentsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Torrent torrent = new Torrent();
                    torrent.setUrl(torrentObject.getString(Keys.URL));
                    torrent.setSize(torrentObject.getString(Keys.SIZE));
                    torrent.setQuality(torrentObject.getString(Keys.QUALITY));
                    torrent.setSeeds(Integer.parseInt(torrentObject.getString(Keys.SEEDS)));
                    torrent.setPeers(Integer.parseInt(torrentObject.getString(Keys.PEERS)));
                    torrentList.add(torrent);
                }
                getTorrent();//when this method is called here the list has items on it and it works fine
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

this method uses the `torrentlist` arraylist to download the .torrent file

```
private void getTorrent() {
    String mUrl = torrentList.get(0).getUrl();
    InputStreamVolleyRequest request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, mUrl,
            new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
                    // TODO handle the response
                    try {
                        if (response != null) {
                            String name = movie.getMovie_title() + ".torrent";
                            File torrentDirectory = createFolder();
                            File file = new File(torrentDirectory, name);
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            fos.write(response);
                            Toast.makeText(ViewMovie.this,"Successfully Downloaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO handle the error
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, null);
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack());
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507556/arraylist-empty-after-being-populated-inside-volley-onresponse-callback-method

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix you can try to pass your `ArrayList` to your `getTorrent()` function.

```
getTorrent(torrentList);
```

You will call your function like this.

```
private void getTorrent(ArrayList<Torrent> passedList) {
    String mUrl = passedList.get(0).getUrl();
    // rest of your code here
}
```

But you need to know that, this function will always give you the result of first torrent. Because you are getting `0` index in `ArrayList`. Maybe by passing index also, you can create more functional method.